# FlexSlider click on pictures to bring up LightBox like ability

Tags: image, flexslider, lightbox2

I have a FlexSlider/Carousel plug in working great on my site.  Now, I would like to be able to click on the Slider image to bring up a lightbox like plug in so I can 'blow up' the images to be able to see more detail.  I have read and tried to implement a lightbox: true attribute which sounds like it is supposed to do what I am looking for, but it doesn't seem to work.  I can't click on the slider image to do anything.

```
<div id="main" role="main">
  <section class="slider">
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/2-LOVE.PNG" />
    </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/2-LOVE.PNG" />
    </li>               
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

<!-- FlexSlider -->
<script defer src="~/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    itemWidth: 100,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    },
    lightbox: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs this. Try this:

```html
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <a href="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" data-lightbox="1000 500">
              <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/2-LOVE.PNG" />
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I'm using on a current WordPress project is "Responsive Lightbox" by dFactory. It uses the HTML element rel="lightbox" as a hook. Instant lightbox galleries!

```
<div class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <a href="large-image-01.jpg" rel="lightbox">
              <img src="thumb-image-01.jpg" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="large-image-01.jpg" rel="lightbox">
              <img src="thumb-image-01.jpg" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <a href="large-image-01.jpg" rel="lightbox">
              <img src="thumb-image-01.jpg" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="large-image-01.jpg" rel="lightbox">
              <img src="thumb-image-01.jpg" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul> </div>
```

This is the one that worked for me - I also added a target="blank" to open a new window.